# pnpm Not Installing Transitive Workspace Dependency in NX Monorepo

Tags: pnpm, nx-monorepo

I'm working with an NX monorepo and encountering an issue where a transitive dependency is not being installed as expected with pnpm. My setup involves three packages:

- `parse-matter` (a utility library)
- `vite-plugin-parse-matter` (a plugin depending on parse-matter)
- `demo` (an application depending on vite-plugin-parse-matter)

In `vite-plugin-parse-matter`'s `package.json`, `parse-matter` is listed as a dependency using the workspace protocol:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "parse-matter": "workspace:*"
}
```

Similarly, `demo` lists `vite-plugin-parse-matter` as a dependency, also using the workspace protocol. When I run `pnpm install` in the monorepo, `parse-matter` is not installed or linked in demo's `node_modules`, despite being a second-grade dependency via `vite-plugin-parse-matter`. This leads to errors, `vite-plugin-parse-matter` missing its dependency `parse-matter`.

**My question:**

Why is `parse-matter` not being installed or linked in `demo`'s `node_modules` as a transitive dependency of `vite-plugin-parse-matter` with pnpm, and how can I ensure it is correctly resolved without adding `parse-matter` directly as a dependency of `demo` or using peer-dependencies?